# Can you define an In App Purchase and submit app for review without using it?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, subscription

We want to add in app purchase (auto renewable subscription) to our app. We do it on a separate branch and don't want it to be part of the app until implemented and tested thoroughly.

To support it, we need to define a IAP on app store connect. 
Of course, other features are implemented simultaneously, merged to master, and we submit the app to review once a week.

We are scared that if we'll define the IAP, when submitting to review the IAP will be submitted automatically with the app, before the feature is ready on the client side.

Is it possible to exclude the IAP from review until we are ready to submit it?

If not, how would you approach this?

Comment: Testflight comes in hands

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can select which IAPs you submit for review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you view your IAP on App Store Connect there is a checkbox, "Cleared For Sale". You can keep that unchecked to be safe that your in-app-purchases won't be visible anywhere.